# Hover js function on iPad doesn't toggle

Tags: javascript, ipad, hover

On desktop when hover a `div` some overlay slides down, OKE.

But on my iPad that works on touch, OKE, but no `toggle` when touch again.

The overlay div is always visible after the first click.

```
$('.side').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.txt').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.txt').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(250)
    }
);
```

I have a example here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/87011nkx/

Any idea how to fix this for ipad - `toggle` function?

Comment: How exactly would you define a _"hover"_ event on a touch device? Do you expect your code to be psychic, and respond to the users' finger hovering over the display? PS: it's ***toggle***, not _troggle_

Comment: lol never knew it was toggle, always thought it was troggle :)
I need on hover to toggle the overlay. is that possible?

Comment: Just look at what the hover event entails: the cursor is hovering over an element, without interacting with it. touch devices don't have a cursor, users use their fingers. Whenever they interact with elements, they _touch_ the element (~= a click). If they hover over the interface, there is no interaction and therefore, there are no events to be handled

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I understand why it doesn't work. dfsq gave the answer to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement custom `hover` functionality with touch events support. Looks like something like this would be enough in this case:

```
$('.side').on({
    'mouseenter mouseleave touchstart': function(e) {
        var $txt = $(this).find('.txt'),
            type = e.type == 'mouseenter' || (e.type == 'touchstart' && !$txt.is(':visible'));
        $txt[type ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp'](250);
    }
});
```

Comment: Any idea how to do it on my show hide javascript function? (I'm not a coder) http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/k87r6tps/

Comment: Your attempt is correct. Just make sure `thepop` is inside of `.pop-it`.

Comment: ah it's not, good find. I have it kinda working now. Because I have a css pop-it:hover alpha 0 style the pop-it isn't visible any more on ipad after toggle. So I guess I need to add this in my js. I will make a new post for this. Thanks!